# db2 database creation

Tags: database, db2

I installed db2 client in my system for personal use. I am not able to understand from where to create the database so that i can create tables on that db and play around with sql queries as of now.

This is totally related to my personal use and learning purpose.

Please inform how to create a dummy database and play around with it with db2 client?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DB2 client is just that - a client only.  It does not include the database engine.

To create a database you have to install the server.  The server includes the client portions.

Answer (score 8):

Are you on Windows?  Are you using [DB2 Express-C](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/im/udbexp/)?  I'm assuming you are, since you say this is for personal work.

After you have the DB2 binaries installed, you should have been prompted with the "DB2 First Steps" application, where you could have the application go through a GUI to create the database for you.  If you missed it, you should be able to find it in your start menu with `Start -> Programs -> IBM DB2 -> DB2COPY1 (Default) -> Set-up Tools -> First Steps`.

If you prefer the command line, you can use the following:

First, determine if your installation created a default instance (on Windows, this will be called `DB2`) by using the `db2ilist` command.  In the DB2 Command Window, if you're not on the instance you want to create a database in, you can switch with the following command:

```
set db2instance=DB2
```

Be sure to not include spaces around the equal sign.

Now, in order to create a database in the current instance, you use this command:

```
db2 create database mydatbase
```

For further reading, IBM has [produced a Getting Started ebook](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/db2/express-c/wiki/Getting_Started_with_DB2_Express_v9.7_p4.pdf), and I would highly recommend you check it out!

Comment: Hi, Yes, I am on windows but its not a Express-C. Its the full version, on the setup Launchpad, i got the options: DB2 Enterprise Server Edition(Install New/Work With Existing), DB2Client(Install New/Work With Existing) and IBM Db Addin for VS 2005 Install. I installed DB2 client v9.1 from there and got Command Editor, Control Centrol, Configuration Assistant, etc. But now i am not able to add a dummy database for my personal use. i tried the command db2 create db <dbname> as you suggested and it worked in cmd without error but then i cant add that db in command editor, its not getting picked.

Comment: You may need to go in Configuration Assistant, and set that database up as a data source.  There's a wizard under the `Selected` menu, `Add Database Using Wizard`.

Comment: Also, what version are you using?  If your server is also v9.1 like your client, that version is well out of date, and went out of support in April (2012).

Comment: Is there something like the server and the client have to be of same version? I am able to add database and test the connection using the Configuration Assistant, the connection shows successfull. Also, using the Control Center, i am able to connect to the database successfully. But when i try to connect the database using Command Editor, i am getting an exception with sqlcode:-1042 and sqlstate:58004. Do i need some fix pack for my Command Editor? If am able to connect to the database successfully using Configuration Assistant and Control Center then why the Command Editor throwing exception?

Comment: Check out the [Info Center page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql01042c.html) for that error message.  It has some problem resolutions that may help you fix your problem.

Comment: I'm also going to mention that IBM is going to deprecate Command Editor and Control Center in favor of [IBM Data Studio](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/im/data/).  Starting with v10, they don't even include those programs with the installer.